# How to use iOS keychain in Oracle MAF application?

Tags: ios, oracle, cordova-plugins, keychain, oracle-maf

I am pretty new to Oracle MAF framework. I want to store a string to iOS keychain and retrieve later. I have searched for a tutorial and still unable to find. 
Please share any tutorial if anyone has done this before. Also I want to know whether we can use a Cordova plugin such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ios-keychain directly in the MAF project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem. I would like to share how did I manage to do. Cordova plugin can be used in the MAF application. MAF app's java code can invoke javascript methods in the cordova plugin. Or we can write a javascript class to do the bridging between MAF app and the cordova plugin.

This is a good tutorial for your reference.
https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/integrating-a-custom-cordova-plugin-into-a-maf-app